# Mobile site CSS looks different in devtools to actual devices, and I can't find the override

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, plugins, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a wordpress/woocommerce website (using the Flatsome theme if it's important) and I am having some CSS issues with the mobile menu overlay. When I preview my mobile site using chrome dev tools everything looks as expected (centered options, large enough to be easy to use, etc) but when viewing the site on actual devices the menu is being forced edge-to-edge in a small, cramped, italicized font. I cannot seem to figure out where it's being overridden, or why it looks different from dev tools to actual use.

This is what it SHOULD look like according to dev tools:
[MENU-CHROME-EMULATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG4JE.jpg)

But this is what is ACTUALLY looks like:
[MENU-ACTUAL-ANDROID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhL8o.jpg)

My website is: [TARGET-WEBSITE-CITRUSBOOKBINDERY](https://www.citrusbookbindery.co.uk/)

Answer (score 1):

FOUND IT! It was actually a conflict with the SG Optimizer plugin rather than a CSS issue, which is why I couldn't find it for so long. I thought I had checked all my plugins, but must have missed that one out. I'll leave the question up in case it can help someone else, though.